# How to solve a Python Flask Socket Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, ubuntu-18.04, putty

I am new to Python and Python-Flask and have ran into an error. 
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Python 2.7.15+ to build a python-flask web application.

When I try to run the application I run into the following error:

```
  File "home_page.py", line 61, in <module>
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
  File "/home/XXXXXXX/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/XXXXXXX/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

One of the fixes I have found was to close the window of puTTY (which I am using to access a VM) however, this doesnt seem the best way to solve this issue.

I am unsure how to proceed with this error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please put whole `traceback`. To see which line of your code gives the error.

Comment: Most likely some other application is already listening to the same port as you're trying to. This also can be a previously running instance of your app.

Comment: `netstat -lpn | grep :80 ` will give you the running process on port 80 (.i.e. `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1607/apache2
`. Kill the process using process id (1607 for the above) `kill -9 1607`. Use `sudo` if required.

Comment: Updated error to show full traceback error.

Comment: is this working correctly when you start Flask first time ? How do you run it? How do you stop it? Normally `Ctrl+C` should stop Flask and port should be available for next run. If you run it in background then it may still running when you try to run it again.

Comment: @furas i type python filename.py to run the app. It works first time and to stop the app I use Ctrl+C. Then when I go to run the app again I get the error.

Comment: system sometimes blockes port for short time for some reason but only if socket wasn't closed correctly. But I never had this problem when I stop Flask using `Ctrl+C`. Besides in `debug` mode Flask should automaticaly reload code when you change some file and there is no need to restart it manually. I use Linux Mint based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should work for you.

```
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", 
    port=5000,
    debug=True,
    threaded=True)
```

Putting `port` parameter with the `value` will enable your `API` to run on desired port.

Additional `threaded` parameter will help your `API` serve multiple request at a time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still get an error when typing this in. [Errno -2] instead of [Errno 98]

Comment: Can you please show the full error ?.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your own port, don't use the reserved port `80`. So you will change the following:

```
app.run("0.0.0.0:4000", debug=True)
```

Take a look at this as well regarding reserved ports: [Reserved TCP/IP ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906613/reserved-tcp-ip-ports)

Comment: instead of [Errno 98] it changes to [Errno -2] once i change the port number to "0.0.0.0:4000"